# Securing WCF Service Calls and establishing session from non-Windows Mobile Client. (e.g. iPhone)

Tags: iphone, wcf, security, authentication, mobile

We would like to achieve following very general, day to day scenario in any web app. We would like to secure a call from non-windows client (i.e. non .NET client) to WCF web service. Client is mobile device (iPhone, Android or Blackberry, but should work on all of them) and also assume native app will be a banking (finance) domain app . So security cannot be compromised.

1. User will be provided a screen to enter username and password.
2. WCF Service call will authenticate the user credentials ( we would want to know how to secure this WCF service call)
3. After successful authentication, all the subsequent call does not have to pass username and password.
4. Each service call should be able validate the credentials or check  whether it is a already authenticated user and if it is then load user roles from some store to authorize the call.

As you can understand we are looking for secure session from a now windows client to WCF Services. Looking forward for a solution ( avoiding ASP.NET sessions) to secure every service call and to authorize call.

Please reply back with code, configuration

Thanks and regards,

Milind

Answer (score 2):

That is perhaps day to day scenario in web app but not in the service. Day to day scenario with a service is authentication in each call and avoiding any session as much as possible.

The answer to your security requirement is HTTPS. That will ensure that the communication will not be compromised. The answer to your authentication requirement is Basic authentication (and perhaps custom HTTP module for handling authentication if you host the service in IIS) or UserName token profile for passing credentials in message body (only SOAP services).

User will be able to provide his credentials in your mobile application but your mobile application should use these credentials for every call to the service (in .NET world these credentials are set only once for communication proxy but that is just implementation - they are still send within each call).

WCF supports security session implemented on top of WS-SecureConversation but neither of mobile platform supports it and it is pretty tough specification so you will no try to implement it yourselves (if you do, you can sell it as separate project). Moreover with very poor SOAP support on iPhone you will most probably use REST service where nothing like secure conversation or even session exists.

If you want any session you will have to use ASP.NET Session (= AspNetCompatibility) or you will have to implement your own session management and pass session token in cookie (= generally same mechanism as ASP.NET session) or in message body (= generally what WS-SecureConversation does but it handles all security stuff around this).